# Pick an image from the image gallery in android?

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

I am naive in android.I am facing a `nuNullPointerException` when i picking an image from the gallery.my code is following like that  and getting error in cursor and `filePathColumn[0]`. What to do..

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        decodeFile(picturePath);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete Code for selecting image from gallery or taking picture from camera..100% working.

```
 protected static ImageView imPhoto;
        private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
        int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
        String selectedImagePath;


    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.registration);

    imPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectImage();
                }
            });
    }

     private void selectImage() {

            final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                    "Cancel"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registration.this);
            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                private DialogInterface dialog;
                private int item;

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    this.dialog = dialog;
                    this.item = item;
                    if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                    } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                                SELECT_FILE);
                    } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }


    ublic void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                    onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
                else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                    onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }
        }

        private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
            byte[] byteArray = bytes.toByteArray();
            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            imPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
                    null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

            Bitmap bm;
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
            int scale = 1;
            while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                    && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;
            options.inSampleSize = scale;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);

            imPhoto.setImageBitmap(bm);


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code for opening in the image gallery.

```
 Intent browseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(browseIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

and below code for pick the image from gallery.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                try {
                    byte[] b;
                    Log.d("picture", imagePath);
                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
                    b = baos.toByteArray();
                    encodedImageToBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                index = imagePath.lastIndexOf("/");
                attachmentImageName = imagePath.substring(index + 1);


  }
 }
```

may this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code. it works for me.

mainactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
        android:text="Load Picture" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String image_str,res,imgDecodableString,the_string_response;
    Bitmap img;
    Exception e;
    int contentLength;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        //Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString), 500, 500, false);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(img);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // find the views
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.uploadImage);
    uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);

    // on click select an image
    selectImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectImageButton);
    selectImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImageFromGallery();

        }
    });
}


public void selectImageFromGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            PICK_IMAGE);
}

/**
 * Retrives the result returned from selecting image, by invoking the method
 * <code>selectImageFromGallery()</code>
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        decodeFile(picturePath);

    }
}

/**
 * The method decodes the image file to avoid out of memory issues. Sets the
 * selected image in to the ImageView.
 *
 * @param filePath
 */

public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Here is the complete code. But still getting error on cursor. In besides, here used contentResolver query stuff.What I think I should add some extra code for that.Can someone tell me about contentResolver and my problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying it by yourself, take a look at `recent-images` library. It can help you. [here](https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images) is the link.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this...**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```