# ANDROID: Take a photo and Share it

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-image, android-file, android-camera-intent

i'am trying to create a simple app that has an activity with 2 buttons(make photo and share it):

1. on click opens a native camera;
2. user makes a photo;
3. camera closed --> we are turning back to our activity;
4. review the photo (inside imageView). however its already saved.
5. now if we click the second button --> We are sharing the photo. Opens a dialog and shows every app that can share image.

Ok. That's how it should be at the end. :)
For now i am just trying to get the real image and not its scaled down thumbnail.
I have found this code, but it returns scaled down image:

```
public class CameraDemo extends Activity {

Button ButtonClick;
int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2; 
int  TAKE_PICTURE=0;
Camera camera;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ButtonClick =(Button) findViewById(R.id.Camera);
    ButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }
    });        
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if( requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
    {   
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PhotoCaptured);
        image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(demo.this, "Picture NOt taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

}
}
```

**How can i return full sized image or at least the path to full sized image? 
Because i want to share full sized photo and not scaled down thumbnail.**

Comment: Check this answer.. it can be useful.. its my answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607014/pick-an-image-from-the-image-gallery-in-android/33607169#33607169

Comment: hi, thx for the answer. after i have made a photo i need to receive fullsized image or path to it. your code in the method onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) saves an image that was scaled down to the root; but imageView receive scaled image from data. How i can receive full sized photo to the imageview jsut after i made a photo?